# pintar filas con distintos colores

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una función (finalizaCompeticion) para poder acceder al DOM desde js y cambiar el fondo de una lista por ejemplo, la fila 1 color verde, fila 2 azul, fila 3 rojo y si solo tengo una fila que sea de un color determinado...al clickar en "AÑADE PARTICIPANTE" muestro la lista en mi html, y al clickar en "FINALIZA COMPETICION" debería cambiarme de color las filas...como podría hacerlo?

html:

```
<input type="text" id="nombre_form" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
      <select id="color_form">
            <option value="red">rojo</option>
            <option value="green">verde</option>
            <option value="blue">azul</option>
            <option value="yellow">amarillo</option>
            <option value="pink">rosa</option>
            <option value="brown">marron</option>
            <option value="violet">violeta</option>
            <option value="orange">naranja</option>
        </select>
   
        <input onclick="muestraConColor()" type="button" value="AÑADE PARTICIPANTE"></input>
    
        <input onclick="finalizaCompeticion()" type="button" value="FINALIZA COMPETICION"></input>
```

```
js:
```

```
  
var nombre= document.getElementById("nombre_form").value;  
var color= document.getElementById("color_form").value;
const ol = document.createElement("ol");
const li = document.createElement("li");
li.style.color=color;
li.innerText=nombre;
ol.appendChild(li);
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(ol);

 }
```

Comment: Amigo, utilizaste parte de mi respuesta y ni la puntuaste .-. jajajaj todo chill, pero amigo no puedes dividir una pregunta en varias para hacerla colar y que te resuelvan el problema, tu codigo ni si quiera tiene una tabla. Te recomiendo que leas [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), un saludo.

Comment: buenas,  tu aporte como tu mismo has dicho "es decorativo" si miras detenidamente verás que de tu respuesta no usé absolutamente nada, eso si, agradezco que amplíes el contenido, lo siento porque  he olvidado puntuarte, ya lo hice si te interesa saberlo :)  El resto de cosas que comentas, tomo nota, un saludo ! :)

Comment: Todo chill carlos, que bueno que hayas encontrado la solucion pero recuerda siempre hacer el intento por tu cuenta y luego si no podes, procedes a peguntar, asi la pregunta siempre sera bien recibida, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Es mejor usar `appendChild` a un `ol`, no hacer un nuevo `ol` cada vez. Tu lista solo obtiene el número 1 porque tienes muchas listas con un `li`.
2. Puedes usar `lista.childNodes.forEach` para obtener los `li`s y les das `style`.

```js
function muestraConColor() {
  const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_form").value;
  const color = document.getElementById("color_form").value;
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.style.color = color;
  li.innerText = nombre;
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(li);
}

function finalizaCompeticion() {
  const lista = document.getElementById("lista");
  lista.childNodes.forEach((li) => {
    if (!li.style.backgroundColor) {
      li.style.backgroundColor = li.style.color;
      li.style.color = "#fff";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombre_form" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
<select id="color_form">
  <option value="red">rojo</option>
  <option value="green">verde</option>
  <option value="blue">azul</option>
  <option value="yellow">amarillo</option>
  <option value="pink">rosa</option>
  <option value="brown">marron</option>
  <option value="violet">violeta</option>
  <option value="orange">naranja</option>
</select>

<input onclick="muestraConColor()" type="button" value="AÑADE PARTICIPANTE"></input>

<input onclick="finalizaCompeticion()" type="button" value="FINALIZA COMPETICION"></input>

<div id="div1">
  <ol id="lista"></ol>
</div>
```